# Current state of Tinc 1.1?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, tinc

So as probably any Tinc user ( www.tinc-vpn.org ), I noticed there are two versions: 1.0 and 1.1. On the website is explained that 1.1 is the stepping stone for 2.0 and that it has a lot of neat features *planned*.
However, in the repositories, one usually finds version 1.0, and since I'm someone who prefers having everything run through repositories instead of manually updated, I want to know if it's  worth it, and if it's actually in a usable state, and if any of the 'planned' features are implemented.

In short, does anyone know what the current state of Tinc 1.1 is?

Comment: Have you tried posting the same question to the mailing list?

Comment: I posted on the mailing list, I referred this post too, if I get advice in the mailing list that isn't posted here I'll update my post or post an answer to my own question.

Comment: I have gotten a reply from the developer which I'd love to put in an answer here. Basically he says this: Control socket feature is implemented, replaceable cryptography not yet, Automatic connection management'mostly' implemented (see the autoconnect option), automate setting up nodes is mostly implemented (see tinc init command). If you disable the experimental protocol features (ExpewrimentalProtocol = no), you can upgrade an existing 1.0 node to 1.1 and use it with the existing 1.0 nodes, and switch back if you don't like it, without issues.